# cPanel api2 for MysqlFE authorizehost

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to use cPanel xml api to add ip addresses to the mysql remote access host list.

If I use this...

```
$newdomain = "12.345.45.678";
$myemails = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "MysqlFE", "authorizehost", array('host'=>$newdomain) );
```

I can in fact add the ip to the remote host access list. I verified by logging into cPanel and checking.
When I try to access the database remotely, I am blocked. ???? like I have not whitelisted my ip ??

If I log into cPanel and remove the ip address and add it manually(the exact same ip)...then test my remote connection, and it works.

Am I missing something here?
The xmlapi adds the ip successfully, but I still can't get a remote connection.

If it helps at all, my whitelist already has some ip addresses that were added manually. So, it is not an empty record.

Comment: I wonder if there is supposed to some kind of delimiter I am supposed to add before the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once("xmlapi.php");
$ip = 'website ip address here';
$account = 'cpanel username here';
$domain = 'mysite.com';
$passwd = 'cpanel password here';

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
$xmlapi->password_auth($account, $passwd);
$xmlapi->set_port(2083);
$xmlapi->set_output("simplexml");

$newAuthIP = "123.45.67.890";  <----- sanitized value from a form post
$myemails = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "MysqlFE", "authorizehost", array('host'=>$newAuthIP) );
?>
```